# Weird infinite loop in the console but not in the Applet - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I'm a complete novice in Java.
I'm writing a program which got stuck in an infinite loop which is displayed in the console but not in the Applet. It's a calendar which needs to change the month and date form October 31st to November 1st and display this in a location. I'm pretty sure the if statement is wrong but I can't find anything in my books to help :(
here is the code:

```
            int date = 28;
            String currentMonth = "October";
            String nextMonth = "November";
            String dateNumber = "28th October";

            for (date = 28; date <= 32; date++)
            {
                if (date == 32);
                {
                    currentMonth = nextMonth;
                    date = 1; 
                }


                switch (date)
                {
                case 28: dateNumber = "28th October"; break;
                case 29: dateNumber = "29th October"; break;
                case 30: dateNumber = "30th October"; break;
                case 31: dateNumber = "31st October"; break;
                case 32: dateNumber = "1st November"; break;
                default: println (dateNumber); break;
                }

                GLabel label = new GLabel(dateNumber);
                label.setFont ("Ariel-13");
                label.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                add (label, 50, 001 + (100*date));
            }
```

In the console it repeats 28th October infinitely. In the Applet it shows "28th October" in the first position of the `GLabel` only (it does not execute the `+ (100*date)`). 
I would be very grateful if somebody can explain what's happening and suggest a way to fix it!

Comment: Never **ever** change the loop variable within the loop!!

Answer (score 5):

You put semicolon `;` at the end of `if` statement.

```
if (date == 32)  // Remove ;
{
```

Due to semicolon at the end of `if`, won't enter on `if` block, So your `date` is not re-initiate to `1`.

Comment: also, on the switch-case - "date" will never be 32 as it is altered to 1 before it reaches the switch. This is a bug because dateNumber will be wrong

Comment: OK but unfortunately the problem is the same even when I delete the semicolon after the if statement. Only now it repeats "31st October" in the Applet as well as in the console... It doesn't execute the switch and it doesn't break from the loop

Comment: Also if I change the last case from `case 32: dateNumber = "1st November"; break;` to `case 01: dateNumber = "1st November"; break;` it starts repeating "1st November"